# There is DateTime operator + (DateTime d, TimeSpan t), but there is no DateTime operator + (TimeSpan t, DateTime d)

Tags: c#, .net

I parse user supplied expressions, and it's very inconvenient that user can `DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1)`, but can't `TimeSpan.FromDays(1) + DateTime.Now`.
Any reason it's not implemented and how to fix this (beside `DateTime.Add`)?

Comment: You'd have to ask Microsoft. Barring a response from them, the question is primarily opinion based, as well as being unclear and lacking in focus (i.e. what's "broken" about the current situation and what "fix" do you expect?). That said, it seems likely to me that at least part of why it is the way it is, is because when overloading operators, it's good design to match related operators, like `+` and `-`, but it's not clear what `TimeSpan - DateTime` would mean.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `DateTime` + `TimeSpan` => `DateTime` so `TimeSpan` + `DateTime` might make some people think it should return a `TimeSpan` instead?

Comment: I have to wonder what you think `TimeSpan + DateTime` would do, if not exactly the same thing as `DateTime + TimeSpan`.

Comment: Is this question related to [DynamicExpresso library](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso)? In this case I suggest to open an issue on the github repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators in C# are static members of the *left* hand side object. So the operator would be a static member of the `TimeSpan` class. `TimeSpan` does have an add operator to add another `TimeSpan`, but not a `DateTime`.

Probably because semantically it seems odd to say "2 days plus January 4th, 2021", while it *does* make sense to say "January 4th, 2021 plus 2 days", or "2 days plus 4 hours".

For the "why doesn't someone just code it up" question - coding isn't free. It takes time (and money) to design, built, implement, test, document, and support features. It may not be worth it for this feature when there's an easy solution (just change the order of the operands).